# Ubuntu 12.04 freezes after login

Tags: 12.04

I installed Ubuntu 12.04 to dual boot with Windows 7 on an ACER netbook. The netbook boots to Ubuntu without a problem but freezes at login or right after. Nothing moves and nothing responds. I have to shut down the computer to restart it.
Any suggests as to how to correct the problem?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What should I do when Ubuntu freezes?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/4408/what-should-i-do-when-ubuntu-freezes)

Answer (score 1):

On some aspire netbooks you need to enable you need to turn on network boot in the BOIS. See more here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AspireOne722#Booting_USB_media.